# The meaning of "but or ever"

Tags: meaning, grammar, archaicisms

In this fragment from *The Rime of the Ancient Mariner*, what does *but or ever* mean?

> I looked to heaven, and tried to pray;
>   **But or ever** a prayer had gusht,
>   A wicked whisper came, and made
>   My heart as dry as dust.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*But* and *ever* hold their usual meanings, the tricky one is '***or***'. It would appear to be an archaic or dialectic form for 'before'

[from Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/or#Translations)

> Preposition
>   **or**
>
> (now archaic or dialect) Before; ere.   
> Quotation  
> 1485, Sir Thomas
>   Malory, Le Morte d’Arthur, Book VII:
>   *"Sey ye never so," seyde Sir Bors, "for many tymys or this she hath bene wroth with you, and aftir that she was the firste that repented
>   hit."*

Comment: Yes, so the line in contemporary English would be: But before ever a prayer had gushed.

Comment: It's actually a variant form of the word in the W definition that has survived only slightly longer: *ere*.  Archaicizing poets tended to prefer *or* with *ever* because *ever* is so frequently reduced in poetry to *e'er*, pronounced exactly like *ere*.